# Many objects to one Object using jolt

Tags: java, json, jolt

Hi working in Jolt transformation tool and getting know some in-depth details
Input

```json
{
  "characteristic": [
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicName",
      "value": "availableBalance",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicValue",
      "value": "2999.25",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicName",
      "value": "Name",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicValue",
      "value": "Jack",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicName",
      "value": "Likes",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "usageCharacteristicValue",
      "value": "Code",
      "@type": "usageCharacteristic",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt Spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "arrayIndex": {
            "2": {
              "@(2,value)": "data.queryBalance.accountBalance"
            },
            "0": {
              "@(2,value)": "data.queryBalance.Name"
            },
            "1": {
              "@(2,value)": "data.queryBalance.Likes"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output :

```json
{
  "data" : {
    "queryBalance" : {
      "accountBalance" : [ "availableBalance", "2999.25" ],
      "Name" : [ "Name", "Jack" ],
      "Likes" : [ "Likes", "Code" ]
    }
  }
}
```

the Output i was getting is not good enough for me, want to do like String like bellow Expected.

Expected Output :

```
"availableBalance" : "2999.25",
"Name" : "Jack",
"Likes" : "Code"
```

how do i get like a String ?

Comment: Jolt converts a JSON value into a JSON value. Considering `"availableBalance" : "2999.25"` is not a valid JSON, I presumed that you need to get such a result `{
  "value" : "availableBalance : 2999.25"
}`, don't you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solve the problem
spec

```json
[
  {
    //group keys and valeus for arrayIndex
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "value": "newArray[@(1,arrayIndex)].@(1,name)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //create a new object use a key and valeus matchs previous
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "newArray": {
        "*": {
          "usageCharacteristicValue": "@(1,usageCharacteristicName)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

output

```json
{
  "Name" : "Jack",
  "Likes" : "Code",
  "availableBalance" : "2999.25"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **modify** transformation spec as well such as

```json
[
  {
   // reduce to simple array "value" : [ "availableBalance", "2999.25" ] nested within an object
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // combine components of the array so as to reform as a string
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(' : ',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit**: You can alternatively try the following for the new case :

```json
[
  {
    // dissipate each array into different object with respect to arrayIndex values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "@(1,arrayIndex).&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // combine components of each array colon-separatedly
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join(' : ',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // convert to a unique array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // combine components of each array comma-separatedly
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(' , ',@(1,value))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: well try, working for only two Objects in the list. similarly have more objects differentiate with array index. similar arrayIndex 0bjects have to get like String can u give one more try :)

Comment: Hi @SivaPrasadVajja . Can you rephrase what exactly needed by considering the issue I've already mentioned through editing the question please ?

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, have updated Question as per new requirement. please check now!

Comment: I've just added the new case @SivaPrasadVajja but I see that the desired output is not a valid JSON yet, I think you meant to have `{
  "value" : "availableBalance : 2999.25 , Name : Jack , Likes : Code"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it by another library *Josson*. You may consider to use it.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(inputJSON);
```

---

Transform to an array of string

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "characteristic" +
    ".group(arrayIndex)" +
    ".concat(elements[name='usageCharacteristicName'].value" +
    "       ,' : '" +
    "       ,elements[name='usageCharacteristicValue'].value)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ "availableBalance : 2999.25", "Name : Jack", "Likes : Code" ]
```

---

Transform to a single string

```
String str = josson.getString(
    "characteristic" +
    ".group(arrayIndex)" +
    ".concat(elements[name='usageCharacteristicName'].value" +
    "       ,' : '" +
    "       ,elements[name='usageCharacteristicValue'].value)" +
    ".join(', ')");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output

```
availableBalance : 2999.25, Name : Jack, Likes : Code
```

---

Transform to a map

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "characteristic" +
    ".group(arrayIndex)" +
    ".map(elements[name='usageCharacteristicName'].value::elements[name='usageCharacteristicValue'].value)" +
    ".mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "availableBalance" : "2999.25",
  "Name" : "Jack",
  "Likes" : "Code"
}
```

---

Transform to a map with sorted "arrayIndex" as key

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "characteristic" +
    ".group(arrayIndex)" +
    ".sort(arrayIndex)" +
    ".map(arrayIndex.prepend('arrayIndex')::" +
    "       concat(elements[name='usageCharacteristicName'].value" +
    "             ,' : '" +
    "             ,elements[name='usageCharacteristicValue'].value))" +
    ".mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "arrayIndex0" : "Name : Jack",
  "arrayIndex1" : "Likes : Code",
  "arrayIndex2" : "availableBalance : 2999.25"
}
```